# My makefile tries to compile a directory

Tags: c, makefile

The output of `make` is as follows

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -o bin/test src/obj/ src/obj/main.o  src/obj/test.o 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find src/obj/: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

As you can see, the executed compile command is trying to compile src/obj/ as an object file. My best guess is that somehow it's been listed in the OBJ variable.

EDIT: This is now a working makefile. I made the following changes after some debugging.

This wasn't working. The file paths were all mixed up by the time it compiled.
So this...

```
# object directory
OBJ_DIR=$(SRC_DIR)/obj

# souce files
SRC=$(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)

# object files
OBJ=$(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.c, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(SRC)) # still directories in OBJ list causing problems
```

became this...

```
# object directory
OBJ_DIR=obj

# souce files
SRC=$(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.c,%.c,$(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c))

# object files
OBJ=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC))
```

and this...

```
# rule that individual objects rely on .c versions and .h files
# needs to compile to .o files, then compile to executable
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

# actual compile commands
$(PROJ_NAME): $(OBJ_DIR)/$(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJ_DIR)/$(OBJ)
```

became this...

```
# rule that individual objects rely on .c versions and .h files
# needs to compile to .o files, then compile to executable
%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

# actual compile commands
$(PROJ_NAME): $(SRC_DIR)/$(OBJ_DIR)/$(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(SRC_DIR)/$(OBJ_DIR)/$(OBJ)
```

Essentially, using `patsubst` I made sure that all the files in the list had no path attatched to them, and then manually specified the full path when needed.

Comment: Use [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) as `remake -x` or `make --trace` to understand what is going on (assuming GNU make & Linux).

Answer (score 3):

Theses two lines

```
 $(PROJ_NAME): $(OBJ_DIR)/$(OBJ)
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJ_DIR)/$(OBJ)
```

are probably wrong, since `$(OBJ)` already contains `$(OBJ_DIR)`

So use

```
 $(PROJ_NAME): $(OBJ)
      @echo OBJ= $(OBJ) at= $@ caret= $^
      $(COMPILE.c) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

instead. Learn more about GNU make builtin rules (you'll get them with `make -p`). When you are satisfied, remove the debugging `@echo` line.

As I commented, use [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) as `remake -x` or `make --trace` to understand what is going on (assuming GNU make & Linux).

You may want to use the [strip](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions) function to remove  leading and trailing whitespace, e.g.

```
  OBJ= $(strip $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.c, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(SRC)))
```

Be sure that your `OBJ_DIR` definition (and other definitions in your `Makefile`) does not contain trailing spaces. Don't put comments in them:

```
#be sure that following line does not have comments or trailing spaces
OBJ= $(strip $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.c, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(SRC)))
```

Putting `#` comments in line defining *make* variables is a very bad habit.
You should put comment lines before or after the definition line.

Comment: Yeah I'm using Ubuntu. remake tells me it's line 61 - the line you pointed out. But I get the same error with both versions.

Comment: And I've double checked all the lines and removed end of line comments. Still no luck.

Comment: Then, invest more of your time, using `remake -x` and `make --trace` appropriately

Answer (score 1):

I tried your makefile with a `src` directory containing a `a.c` file.

It appears that `$(OBJ_DIR)/$(OBJ)` expands to `src/obj/ src/obj/a.o`. The variable `$(OBJ)` probably contains empty strings or spaces

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is definitely related to the comments at the end of macro definitions.  The `#` should only be used on a macro line to embed spaces at the end of the macro definition, which you did by mistake with unwanted obscure consequences.

Here are some more hints and remarks:

You can use the `:=` operator to evaluate macros at parse time, which may be more appropriate for `$(wildcard..)` and `$(shell...)` expansions.

```
SRCS:=$(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)
```

For clarity, you should use plural identifiers for lists of things: `SRCS` and `OBJS`. `OBJS` should just be the list of object files with the path included. I don't understand why you insist on stripping the paths from the source and objects file lists.  Gnu Make generic rules makes it easy to specify different compile options for different output source and/or object directories.  You can take advantage of this to make different targets, such as 32 and 64 bits versions, from the same sources and let them coexists without conflicts.

The final target should be simple:

```
$(PROJ_NAME): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS)
```

Comment: Those didn't seem to work. Can you explain what's wrong with the final target? The list in `OBJ` should be just the single files, requiring a full path to them. Am I wrong here?